# Swift - A way to force redrawing of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an `UIViewController` where there is an `UIScrollView`, there also is a function (`build()`) to draw `UIView`'s in the `UIScrollView`.

**Problem :** Nothing appears in the `UIViewController`, but when I scroll (so when I update the `UIScrollView`) the `UIView`'s, I wanted, appear.

I tried `setNeedsDisplay()` to force the redrawing but it doesn't work...

A video to help you to understand the problem :
https://vimeo.com/user87689481/review/281597574/3cccb78dc1

Here is the code of the `UIViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var body: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            while !Home.accessories.isInitialized {}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.build(Home.accessories.toUIView())
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func build(_ s: [UISectionView]) {
        let topMargin = 10
        let rightMargin = 10
        let leftMargin = 10
        let space = 5
        let heightItem = 60
        var b = topMargin

        for t in s {
            if t.isHidden == true {
                continue
            }
            if t.title != nil {
                let f = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
                let l = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: rightMargin, y : b, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - (rightMargin + leftMargin), height: Int(f!.lineHeight)))
                l.font = f
                l.text = t.title
                body.addSubview(l)
                b = b + Int(f!.lineHeight) + space
            }
            for i in t.items {
                body.addSubview(i.getView(frame: CGRect(x: rightMargin, y: b, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - (rightMargin + leftMargin), height: heightItem), view: self))
                b = b + heightItem + space
            }
        }
        body.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(b))

        //a code to force body (UIScrollView) to refresh/relaod/redraw/update/...
    }

}
```

I hope we can help me =D

Thanks in advance !

Comment: your question is not clear when you want to display ? why you want to redraw ?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear :/ I want to redraw because the app doesn't do it automatically. Maybe the video I had will help you to understand : https://vimeo.com/user87689481/review/281597574/3cccb78dc1

Comment: When you start to scroll the `scrollview` then only your sub view content shows. Is that your problem? If yes means, Check with the real device. That dealy UI update because of you Mac performance support.

Comment: so when you want to appear this in the beginning or after scrolling ?

Comment: in the beginning, I want that every items are on the screen when the app launches

Comment: Put some `print()` statements in your code to help you see when things are being executed - such as a `print("waiting")` *before* your `while` line, a `print("initialized")` *after* the `while` line, and a `print("calling build")` right before `self.build(Home...)`.

Comment: Why are you building them on a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to redraw a `UIScrollView`, then only thing you need to do is:

1. Add views to `UIScrollView`
2. Set `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` so that it allows user to pan around and see all of the contents of the `UIScrollView`

What you are doing in your code seems ok, because you are doing both of the things listed above.

Problem is either if your `t`s are hidden:

```
if t.isHidden == true {
    continue
}
```

Or you are calling `build()` method somewhere else on the Background thread

To be sure you are not doing that you can just add `assert(Thread.isMainThread, "Never call me on background thread")` as the first line in `build()` method

Comment: I don't really understand you comment because the way you propose me to solve my problem is already what I do (I think) :/
Maybe this video will help you to understand the problem : https://vimeo.com/user87689481/review/281597574/3cccb78dc1

Comment: did you add the assert I put in the answer?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed :/

Comment: Add a break point at the line `if t.title != nil {` and see if it gets triggered when you open the view or when you start scrolling

Comment: Nothing, just what Mathi Arasan say : "When you start to scroll the scrollview then only your sub view content shows. Is that your problem? If yes means, Check with the real device. That dealy UI update because of you Mac performance support." It works perfectly on real iOS devices !